# Написание слов с корнем "полу": (полу) румяный, жизнью чуть (полу) задетый

Tags: орфография, приставка-полу

```
  ПОЛУБРАКО-НИЗКОСОРТНЫЙ

 Полу трезвый, полу пьяный,
 В полу рвань  полу одетый,
 Я сижу  полу румяный,
 Жизнью чуть полу задетый.
            
 Жизнь проходит тихо мимо,
 Втихомолку  стороною,
 Скажем так, полу незримо,
 Не  отмеченная  мною.
            
 Сам я весь какой-то смятый,
 В полу пыль полу протёртый,
 Полу зримостью  объятый,
 Полубрако – низкосортный.
           Иловайский Олег
```

**История вопроса:**

1. Орфографический редактор подчеркивает **"полурумяный".**
2. Проверяю **по словарю:** нет такого слова.
3. Смотрю в **[толковый словарь](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83&mode=slovari&l=1&dicts%5B%5D=42):** там дан перечень слов с корнем ***ПОЛУ***. Это **полный** перечень?
4. Как же быть? **Авторская** орфография?
5. Но в результе проведенной работы нахожу **текст**, где много слов с конем ***ПОЛУ.***
6. Уж очень много получается авторской орфографии, или как это **оценить?** И по какому **общему принципу** составлялся список **разрешенных** слов?
7. **Будьте внимательны** при написании слов с корнем ***ПОЛУ***. Самодеятельность здесь **не приветствуется**)

Answer (score 1):

Полу- пишется слитно с любой частью речи.
Источник: https://russkiiyazyk.ru/orfografiya/napisanie-pol-polu-so-slovami.html

Примечание 1. Если вторая часть слова содержит дефис, то дефис также ставится после первой части, например: ... полу-конференц-зал, полу-социал-демократы.
gramota.ru›Учебник грамоты›Правила от азов до тонкостей

Слитно пишутся наречия, начинающиеся с впере-, напере-, впри-, враз-(врас-), вза-, вна-, навы-, впол- (вполу-)
[https://studopedia.ru/8_149270_pravopisanie-narechiy-obrazovannih-ot-sushchestvitelnih.html#:~:text=%D0%9F%D0%B8%D1%88%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%8F%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%81,%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%83%20%D0%BA%20%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BC](https://studopedia.ru/8_149270_pravopisanie-narechiy-obrazovannih-ot-sushchestvitelnih.html#:%7E:text=%D0%9F%D0%B8%D1%88%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%8F%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%81,%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%83%20%D0%BA%20%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BC))%2C%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D1%83

Руководствуясь приведенными правилами можно заключить, что автор стихотворения сделал по одной ошибке в написании слов: полутрезвый, полупьяный, полурвань, полуодетый, полурумяный, полузадетый, полунезримо, полупротертый, полу-брако-низкосортный и две ошибки при написании наречия «вполупыль».
«Авторской орфографией» эти ошибки объяснить вряд ли удастся.

Можно ли и нужно ли ограничивать поэта «списком разрешенных слов»? Думается, что нет. Хочется только, чтобы неологизмы впечатляли яркой образностью, меткостью, но не назойливой многочисленностью или вычурной замысловатостью.

Answer (score 1):

1. «Орфографический редактор» не ищет в написанном смысла, поэтому два (отдельно стоящих) знакомых ему слова «полу» и «румяный» подчеркивать не станет.
   Перечень слов с корнем ПОЛУ в толковом словаре (на который дана ссылка в вопросе) весьма скуден и не содержит даже часто встречающихся слов, например - «полуденный».
   Вот в этом списке  https://wordhelp.ru/contains/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83 уже больше 500 слов, начинающихся с «полу», но и он неполный, поскольку не содержит редко встречающихся слов.
2. Несмотря на свою смысловую неопределенность (румянец слабый или румянец на одной щеке?), а как по мне, так и неказистость, слово «полурумяный» не такое уж и редкое. Оно встречается в косметичке, на кухне, но чаще всего – в поэтических текстах...
   ...полурумяна https://goodvery.ru/item/62253242977
   ...полурумяным https://retsept-salatov.livejournal.com/47860.html
   ...щёки бледные, полурумяные... https://vk.com/wall-182724535_79
   ...закат багряный в вершинах снежистых холмов, и блеск его полурумяный... https://litlife.club/books/273919/read?page=45
   ... обнимался с пухлой, сладострастной... полурумяной, жгучей... https://litlife.club/books/273919/read?page=45
3. Нельзя критиковать (корректировать) поэтические тексты, руководствуясь «списками разрешенных слов». Чтобы вызвать эмоцию, передать смысл, удержать ритм приходится порою обращаться к словам (формам слов), давно вышедшим из употребления, или выдумывать что то новое и необычное.
   «Поэтический текст тяготеет не к общеупотребительной лексике, но к индивидуально-авторской». https://vk.com/@iz.stihi-priznaki-poeticheskogo-teksta
4. Роль «авторской орфографии» в поэтическом тексте мне непонятна. Как «а/о» проявляет себя при чтении текста вслух (декламации)? М.б. стало принято писать стихотворные тексты, «видеть» которые уже достаточно?
5. Что касается пунктуации, то во второй строфе угадывается конструкция с прямой речью: «(Мы) скажем так». Чтобы не загромождать текст кавычками можно «обезличить» прямую речь, заменив «скажем так» на «так сказать».
6. Раз уж мы посмели покуситься на текст второй строфы, то предложим правку двух строк в первой:
   Полутрезвый, полупьяный,
   в полурвань полуодетый,
   полусонный, полурьяный,
   жизнью полу я задетый.

Comment: Спасибо еще раз за подробный ответ и интерес к теме. У меня были  вопросы по написанию отдельных слов, я задам их позже по возможности.

Comment: Я написала бы так:  в полупыль полупротертый, полубрако-низкосортный. А у вас другое мнение?

Comment: По поводу «полу-брако-низкосортный» другое мнение не у меня, а у Лопатина http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=80#pp152 :
§ 152. Недопустимо слитное написание с приставкой или первой частью сложного слова, если вторая часть слова содержит дефис. Слитное написание должно заменяться дефисным, в результате чего возникают написания с двумя дефисами. Например, следует писать: полу-конференц-зал, полу-социал-демократы...

Comment: Получудак, полумудрец, полумечтатель, по мнению окружающих, я в сущности — просто человек. [В. А. Швец. Дневник (1975)].......................................................................................................................................
              ...........«Полуподлец, но есть надежда... « — продекламировала она громко и встала: — Идемте, а то опоздаем к санаторскому обеду. [М. С. Шагинян. Своя судьба (1916)]

Comment: На мой взгляд, правильная орфография здесь: https://present5.com/presentation/85967283_452970303/image-9.jpg
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,но в сети можно встретить и такую:
https://present5.com/presentation/3/215477200_265431071.pdf-img/215477200_265431071.pdf-16.jpg

Answer (score 1):

**О стихотворении**  (художественная форма, тема, идея)

Можно спорить о художественной **форме** стихотворения,  где автор **намеренно нарушает** правила орфографии, чтобы подчеркнуть значимость слова ***«полу».***  Человек как ***полуличность*** — вот основная идея произведения.

Востребованность в обществе и **самоуважение** — одна из основных потребностей. Никому не хочется быть  ***полунезаметным, полунезримым*** и «каким-то смятым». Появляется чувство дискомфорта, ощущение того, что жизнь проходит мимо.  Вроде бы все нормально,  да только один день не отличается от другого — такая вот ***полужизнь.***

Конечно,  **не каждому дано** стать известным писателем, ученым или политиком, и появляется понимание собственной усредненности во всем:  на работе ты не самый главный,  дети подросли и не слушаются, настоящих друзей тоже вроде бы нет. А так хочется быть  самым-самым.

И человек старается найти такое  **пространство**, где он может восполнить эту неудовлетворенность: если не основное занятие, то хотя бы **увлеченность** чем-то.  Вы коллекционируете марки, монеты или что-то еще?  Тогда надо в этой области быть значимым и уважаемым,  добиваться хороших  результатов.  И так во всем. ***Быть лучшим*** и ***быть "зримым*"** в чем-то и где-то — это очень важно.

Answer (score 0):

**Комментарий к ответу**

Спасибо большое за ответ (голос от меня), у меня такой вопрос. Вы не могли бы записать авторский вариант стихотворения **без ошибок** (чтобы я могла однозначно понять ваше решение). Стихотворение можно скопировать https://poembook.ru/poem/2869401-polubrako-nizkosortnyj

А это **дополнительные** вопросы (рассуждния).

(1) Что у нас **со словарями?** Почему в орфографическом словаре есть ***полутрезвый, полупьяный***, а слово ***полурумяный*** подчеркнуто красным цветом, оно не найдено. В толковом словаре приведен **неполный** список? Но почему тогда не отмечено «и другие», как это обычно делается. К тому же орфографический редактор считает, что правильно: *полу румяный*. Как здесь стать грамотным?)

2. Я, к примеру, решила, что нельзя использовать "полурумяный": это будет уже **авторский неологизм.** Получается, что можно придумать **любое** слово, причем все они будут считаться авторскими неологизмами.
3. Кстати, **пунктуация** у автора вроде бы верная и даже грамотная, а орфографические ошибки явно **намеренные**. Может, в этом основная **идея:** человек как ***ПОЛУ Я***. Песня даже есть (с такой орфографией).

Answer (score 0):

Второй комментарий к ответу (от 22 января 2024 г.)

Орфография текста (**все по правилам)**

```
ПОЛУБРАКО-НИЗКОСОРТНЫЙ

Полутрезвый, полупьяный,
В полурвань  полуодетый,
Я сижу полурумяный,
Жизнью чуть полузадетый.
        
Жизнь проходит тихо мимо,
Втихомолку  стороною,
Скажем так, полунезримо,
Не  отмеченная  мною.
        
Сам я весь какой-то смятый,
В полупыль полупротёртый,
Полузримостью  объятый,
Полубрако-низкосортный.
```

1. Одетый (во что?) ***в полурвань***, предложное управление.
2. Стертый (во что?) ***в полупыль***, предложное управление. Сравнить: *стереть (во что?) в пыль.* Но не стереть (как?) вполупыль.
3. ***Полубрако-низкосортный.***  По аналогии со сложным прилагательным полубрачно-низкосортный. Полубрак — полубрачный.

**[Правило](https://studopedia.ru/8_149270_pravopisanie-narechiy-obrazovannih-ot-sushchestvitelnih.html#:%7E:text=%D0%9F%D0%B8%D1%88%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%8F%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%81,%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%83%20%D0%BA%20%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BC)**

Наречия типа ***вполглаза, вполнакала*** следует отличать от похожих словосочетаний предлога в и существительного которое начинается с пол-: выполнить работу ***в полчаса,*** картина ***в полстены***, ***в полжизни*** жизнь и т. д.

**[Правило ПАС § 130, пункт 2](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=70#pp70)**

2. Пишутся через дефис прилагательные, образованные из двух или более основ слов, обозначающих **равноправные** понятия, напр.: выпукло-вогнутый, садово-огородный, научно-технический,  мясо-молочный, звуко-буквенный, фарфоро-фаянсовый, приходо-расходный, спуско-подьёмный.